# Occasional connectivity error in windows AZURE

Tags: c#, winforms, azure, azure-sql-database

I have a DB on Azure connected to WinForms app,with basic subscription in windows azure.

And works well about **95%** of time.

However sometimes i get the error `"A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server....`

this error will disappear in about **1 or 2 minutes**.But all these time my internet connection is good. I can access the Azure Portal as well.

What is this occasional error mean?

Answer (score 1):

The issue occurs because the application is not able to connect to the server. According to your description, it seems that your network is not smooth. Since most of the time it works well.

> But all these time my internet connection is good. I can access the Azure Portal as well.

We can access the azure portal, it doesn’t mean that network works smoothly.

- Please have a try to use telnet command to debug it while get the error info. More info about how to add the telnet command please refer to snapshot.

[image]

```
telnet <myserver>.database.windows.net 1433
```

If telnet is successful, the window will change to a completely blank screen.
If telnet is not successful, please have a try to use

```
tracert  <myserver>.database.windows.net.
```

- We also can increase the connection time,
  Microsoft recommends using a connection timeout of at least 30 seconds.
- As a best practice ensure retry logic is in place.